# Nginx container running inside docker on custom network allow / deny not working

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file with this in:

```
  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginx:1.18.0-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - internal-network
```

In my domains server blocks, I've added

```
allow MY_IP;
deny all;
```

But when accessing the domain, I always get 403.
Checking the logs, I can see that my IP is logged as `121.0.0.0` and not my true IP address. If I add a log into nginx like `add_header X-test "$remote_addr";` I can see the header comes back as `172.19.0.1` which I believe is a docker internal IP address.

I understand this is because I'm using a custom network `internal-network`.

Is there any way for docker to pass on the true client IP to the nginx container?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I see two options, either you use host networking for the container to get the actual IP or you place a reverse proxy before the container that adds the actual IP as an additional header which you can in turn evaluate inside the container.

Comment: I feared this would be the case. A reverse proxy isn't a bad idea. I could even have that as a container which uses host network mode.

Answer (score 0):

Most issues are known to the fact, that nginx reads the configuration from top to down

## The IP restriction

In your example

```
allow MY_IP;
deny all;
```

Looks ok, because

### Nginx Manual says

> The ngx_http_access_module module allows limiting access to certain client addresses.
>
> Access can also be limited by password, by the result of subrequest, or by JWT. Simultaneous limitation of access by address and by password is controlled by the satisfy directive.
>
> Example Configuration
>
> ```
> location / {
>    deny  192.168.1.1;
>    allow 192.168.1.0/24;
>    allow 10.1.1.0/16;
>    allow 2001:0db8::/32;
>    deny  all;
> }
> ```
>
> The rules are checked in sequence until the first match is found. In this >example, access is allowed only for IPv4 networks 10.1.1.0/16 and >192.168.1.0/24 excluding the address 192.168.1.1, and for IPv6 network >2001:0db8::/32. In case of a lot of rules, the use of the ngx_http_geo_module >module variables is preferable.

Since you use containers, you have to verify, in the container, which IP has really been used. I suggest giving a small subnet like /30 or /28 for testing if it's just LAN-IPs after verified the which IP has been used.

Some versions I used in the past had some wired bugs that required to use the deny all line in the first place and after that using allow. I am uncertain whether it was due to a custom source or a bug within my machine.

## Basic Password Authentification

If your IP is changing regularly, then the next aproach is mostly a better solution instead relaying on IP Authentification.

### Nginx Documentation says about Basic auth:

> The ngx_http_auth_basic_module module allows limiting access to resources by >validating the user name and password using the “HTTP Basic Authentication” >protocol.
>
> Access can also be limited by address, by the result of subrequest, or by >JWT. Simultaneous limitation of access by address and by password is >controlled by the satisfy directive.
>
> Example Configuration
>
> ```
> location / {
>    auth_basic           "closed site";
>    auth_basic_user_file conf/htpasswd;
> }
> ```

Furthermore, aside from the use of an IP Restriction, depending on what you intend to safeguard, I recommend password authentication as a better practice in combination.

Reference:
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not sure it helps. I've explained _why_ the IP stuff doesn't work. It's because the IP nginx gets isn't my IP address. It's an internal docker one. I'm aware the allow / deny is working, it's just not getting the right IP.

Comment: That being said, good point about basic auth. I hadn't though of using that.

Comment: that is why i was assuming, that the container gets an incorrect IP, and thereforce suggested to use basic auth either combined or as replacement.